# Problem in conversion of .pb to tflite int8 for Coral Devboard (coral.ai)

Tags: object-detection, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, google-coral, yolov4

I have done the training of model for object detection using yolov4 darkenet Alexyab and then converted the weight file generated to tensorflow lite using this repository
https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite
and I was able to convert the yolo weights to pb and tflite float16, but there is a problem in conversion to tflite int8 using this repo. I tried number of things to convert it to tflite int8.

I am working with coral devboard now which requires tflite int8 quantization, please guide me how to convert the pb weights file to tflite int8.

Version:
tensorflow 1.15
python version 3.6.9
CUDA version V9.1.85

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend using the latest TF version, for example, 2.4.1 or nightly version for the conversion, that are a lot of improvements in TFLite conversion.

The above yolov4 github also requires tf 2.3.0 or above version.

If you have still experiencing on creating a int8 quantized model after upgrading TF version. Please share more details of the error message you've got.

Comment: I used tensorflow 1.15 because the newer versions of tensorflow only supports float quantization and does not support int8 quantization.

Comment: First I did it on tensorflow 2.3.x version and was able to convert .pb file to float16, but for int8 tflite conversion it was unsuccessful so I downgraded the tensorflow version to tf 1.15 in virtual environment to test if it can be done.

Comment: Ok I will try the nightly version as well.

Comment: I am having problem with tensorflow 2.3.0 in conversion

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first convert the yolov4 weights to keras `.h5` weights using [this](https://github.com/david8862/keras-YOLOv3-model-set) repository.

Once you have the `.h5` weights, you can use this code to convert a keras model to tflite.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import numpy
import cv2

def representative_dataset_gen():
  num_calibration_steps = 100 # should be a subset of your dataset size
  imgs = []
  batch_size = 1
  for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
    img = cv2.imread(img_file)
    img = img / 255.0
    img = img.astype(np.float32)
    imgs.append(img)
  
  imgs = np.array(imgs)
  images = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(imgs).batch(1)
  for i in images.take(batch_size):
    yield [i]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("path_to_h5_weights")
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8  # or tf.uint8
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Sources - [Tensorflow Quantization](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization)

[tflite conversion](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/)

[generate representative dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877959/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-representative-dataset-for-tfliteconverter)

Comment: Ok I will try this